# Move text vertically center on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following menu on my website: http://jsfiddle.net/pux7v4tL/

You'll see when you scroll that the header area shrinks. As well as this, I'd like to move my `nav` element to the center of the block, vertically. And then obviously return it to its original state when the user scrolls to the top.

How do I achieve this with my current code?

```js
        $(function(){
            $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
        });

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)
            {
                if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'big')
                {
                    $('#header_nav').data('size','small');
                    $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                        height:'78px'
                    },600);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'small')
                {
                    $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
                    $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                        height:'100px'
                    },600);
                }  
            }
        });
```

```css
#header_nav {
  background: #1588cb;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

body {
    height:9000px
}

nav {
    height:100px
}

nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header style="background-color:#1588cb">
    <div id="header_nav">
  <nav class="primary menu">
      <div class="menu-primary-menu-container">
          <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="menu">
              <li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-44"><a href="/wordpress/">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
 </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your Javascript and CSS code and try again:

Javascript code:

```
$(function(){
    $('header').prepend('<div id="menu-button"></div>');
    $('#menu-button').on('click', function(){
        var menuItems = $(".menu-primary-menu-container");
        menuItems.toggle();
    });
});

$(function(){
    $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)
    {
        $('#header_nav').addClass("new");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#header_nav').removeClass("new");  
    }
});
```

CSS Code:

```css
#header_nav {
    background: #1588cb;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition:all ease 0.3s; -webkit-transition:all ease 0.3s; -o-transition:all ease 0.3s; -ms-transition:all ease 0.3s; -moz-transition:all ease 0.3s;
}
#header_nav.new{
    height : 78px;
    transition:all ease 0.3s; -webkit-transition:all ease 0.3s; -o-transition:all ease 0.3s; -ms-transition:all ease 0.3s; -moz-transition:all ease 0.3s;
}

body {
    height:9000px
}

nav {
    height:100px
}

nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    transition:all ease 0.5s; -webkit-transition:all ease 0.5s; -o-transition:all ease 0.5s; -ms-transition:all ease 0.5s; -moz-transition:all ease 0.5s;
}
.new nav ul{
    top :35%;
    transition:all ease 0.3s; -webkit-transition:all ease 0.3s; -o-transition:all ease 0.3s; -ms-transition:all ease 0.3s; -moz-transition:all ease 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much perfect, @Harsh - is there anyway to make it smoother so it doesn't "bump" so much?

Comment: You are assign height using jquery instead of that just add one class to navigation using jquery and do some css for that class with transition effect..

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What was the problem and how does your code solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery css propery . 
https://jsfiddle.net/pux7v4tL/1/

```
 $(function(){
        $('header').prepend('<div id="menu-button"></div>');
          $('#menu-button').on('click', function(){
              var menuItems = $(".menu-primary-menu-container");
              menuItems.toggle();
        });
    });

    $(function(){
        $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)
        {
            if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'big')
            {
                $('#header_nav').data('size','small');
                $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                    height:'78px'
                },600);
                $('#menu-primary-menu').css('margin-right','50%');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'small')
            {
                $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
                $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                    height:'100px'
                },600);
                $('#menu-primary-menu').css('margin-right','0%');
            }  
        }
        });
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant vertically centered. I could improve my explaining a little - thanks anyway, Vijay :-)